# Ajax espere a otro ajax para pintar resultados

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

tengo esta función que realiza dos peticiones ajax en la cual en la primera saca el turno del trabajador la fecha y el tipo, y en el segundo ajax devuelve el horario segun la linea y el turno, la cosa es que me pinta solo el contenido `<tr><th>Fecha</th><th>Linea</th><th>Turno</th><th>Hora Inicio</th></tr>` que se ejecuta antes del segundo ajax, la pregunta es como puedo hacer para que lo pinte bien, osea que espere se espere para pintar a que se ejecute el segundo ajax

```
$('#turnos').on('click', function(e) { // add event submit
    $('#tbodyturnos').empty()
    var cod = $('#trabajador').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/turnos.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {}
    }).done(function (response) {
        if (response==null) {
            var nuevoturno = "<h3>No Tiene turnos disponibles el fin de semana</h3><br><h5>*Contacte con Oficina para mas informacion</h5>"
        }
        else{
            var nuevoturno = "<tr><th>Fecha</th><th>Linea</th><th>Turno</th><th>Hora Inicio</th></tr>"
            for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) { //cuenta la cantidad de registros
                turno=response[i].Turno
                fecha=response[i].Fecha
                tipo=response[i].Tipo
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'ajax/horario.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    data: {
                        turno:turno,
                        tipo:tipo,
                        fecha:fecha
                    }
                }).done(function (response1) {
                    nuevoturno += "<tr><td>" +
                        fecha + "</td><td>" +
                        tipo + "</td><td>" +
                        turno + "</td><td>" +
                        response1 + "</td></tr>"
                })
            }
            nuevoturno += "<tr><td colspan='4'><h5>* Turno pendiente de confirmacion por parte de la direccion de la empresa</h5></td></tr>"
        }
        $('#tbodyturnos').append(nuevoturno)
        $('#turnosModal').modal('toggle');
    })
});
```

Comment: no seria mejor remplantear tu logica para obtener los datos? es ineficiente hacer tantas solicitudes!

Comment: son pocas peticiones como mucho 2 por eso esta echo asi por sencillez no por otra cosa

Comment: 2 u 3 para algo que se podria hacer en 1 no es eficiente siempre se debe minimizar al maximo las solicitudes al servidor no seria mejor hacer un join?? o tratarlo del lado del servidor y luego responder con json??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recuerda que el objetivo de AJAX es hacer peticiones asíncronas, es decir, el motor hará la peticion al servidor y mientras esta es resuelva, continuará con la ejecución del script. Lo que tu solicitas es hacer una petición síncrona(lo contrario de asíconcrono) para lo cual debes desactivar esta función que AJAX ya trae por defecto. Ejemplo:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'master_ajax.php',
data: {
...
},
async: false,
success: ()=>{
//siguiente peticion al server
   $.ajax({
     url: 'master_ajax.php',
     data: {},
}
})
```

Poniendo tu siguiente peticion dentro de `success` y enviando  a `async` el valor de `false` harás que espere a que se resuelva una petición para lanzar otra.

Nota: Recuerda que `success` equivale a `resuelto correctamente`en caso de que el server devuelva algun tipo de error, la funcion que esta dentro de `success` nunca se ejecutará. Esto depende de tus necesidades.

Suerte!

Comment: Perfecto, no recordaba esta funcion y eso que la utilizo varias veces en el proyecto, pero tu sabes cuando uno se atasca....

Answer (score 0):

lo que debes hacer es  poner $('#tbodyturnos').append(nuevoturno) dentro del done de tu segundo ajax para que lo pinte una vez que regrese la respuesta, otra cosa intenta hacer una sola petición en tu segundo ajax sin utilizar el ciclo puedes enviar un arreglo de datos para tus turnos si es que así lo requieres.

ejemplo:

```
//la variable arrayT puede ser response que te regresa tu primer ajax
    $.ajax({
                        url: 'ajax/horario.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'JSON',
                        data: {'arrayTurnos':JSON.stringify(arrayT)}
                    }).done(function (response1) {//hasta que regrese la respuesta pinta la respuesta
                         $('#tbodyturnos').html(response1)//los turnos
                         $('#turnosModal').modal('toggle');
                    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {//para un mejor control en las respuestas
                        alert( "error" );
                        //$('#tbodyturnos').html("error")
                    })
```

Comment: voy a probar a ver que tal

Answer (score 0):

No te recomiendo usar `async:false` en $.ajax, principalmente porque notaras que cuando se esté realizando la consulta tu sitio web se congelará por unos segundos, esto debido a que detendrás el hilo principal de Javascript hasta que tu consulta se complete, veras un warning en la consola de javascript sobre esto. Y en segundo lugar, es código viejo y difícil de mantener. Te propongo una alternativa más moderna y elegante, [Async/Await](https://javascript.info/async-await) , Promesas y [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios).

```
turnos = async () => {
 let response = await axios.get('ajax/turnos.php');

 if (response != null){
  let response1 = await axios.get('ajax/horario.php');

  nuevoturno += ...
 }
};
```

De esta manera con await, esperaras que cada consulta termine para que el código continue.

Comment: voy a probarlo a ver que tal funciona, con async false funciona perfecto ahora mismo